# Require certain words to appear using scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf, c89

I want `scanf` to accept only certain word, for example, if I want to accept either `foo` or `bar`
from the user, I will write something like:

```c
scanf(/*more input specifiers before and after*/ "%s[foo/bar]", demo);
```

This will return 1 and assign `demo` with user input, only if the user have entered either `foo` or `bar`.

How can I achieve such functionality from `scanf`?

Note: should be compatible with C89 and should work when using `fscanf`.

Comment: Scan in a string and use if statements to check if it's foo/bar? The `scanf()` function itself doesn't support this, as far as I know.

Comment: This has a really strong smell of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Exactly why do you want to use `scanf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scanf()` function reads the data from the `stdin` and stores it according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments. The additional arguments should point to already allocated objects of the type specified by their corresponding format specifier within the format string.

Another work of `scanf()` is that it does returns the number of successfully read items. It has no any working ability to compare the given string like `foo /OR/ bar`.